# Access SSRS from public Web Browser

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services, ssas

I’m trying to find a way on using web based SSRS Report Builder outside of Active Directory environment or using RDP.

Currently I use the ananymous solution. Following is the detail.

In the Data Source Server Type selection, I‘m choosing  “Analysis Service” (Anonymous Authentication is embed in the IIS Server)

[image]

The user access is set by default to Anonymous Authentication.

[image]

This is how I provide the connection detail in SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

And the following is the connection string configuration in SSRS

[image]

Only by choosing the “current Windows User” (without filling any user authentication) the Datasource access in the report builder can be accessed.

[image]

By this solution, I have deep concern about the security of the data source, as the data source become accessible without any authentication.

Is there any other settings or solution to enable me design report in SSRS Report Builder from outside from the server in a more secure way?

Comment: Realise this is "chatty", but Is anyone else not able to view any of those images?

Comment: @Larnu I can see them

Comment: Thanks @Milney I can't access from my phone or PC (and they're not even on the same network). Weird.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this. Set up a VPN instead, then they can be accessed as though they are on the local lan but maintaining security.

Comment: Yes, we are highly aware of this. But is there any mechanism like filling in user / password that map into authorized Active Directory user?

Comment: @Dino Why don't you use a VPN? There is Federated Active Directory but not sure if SSAS supports it and it is much more complicated to set up and overkill for this situation, you probably just want a VPN